# How to open Excel macro files (xlsm) in separate instances of Excel 2016/win10

Tags: excel, regedit, xlsm

Does anyone know what registry keys need to be modified in order to open macro enabled excel files in a separate instance of Excel (ie: separate windows)?

I followed the instructions on the following pages [Microsoft How-To](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2636670) (if you want to open *.xlsx files in separate instances of excel)
and [relation between registry folders and file extensions](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php). The 'Microsoft How-To' link worked nicely and did exactly what it was supposed to do. However, I need xlsm files to open in separate windows and for the xlsx files to continue to open the default way (all in the same window/excel-instance).

I thought if i modified the Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12\shell\open data (similar to what is described in the first link) the *.xlsm files would then always open in a new window each time.

Instead of this working successfully, now when I try to open an *.xlsm file, a blank excel window comes up with no workbook in it (after this failed attempt I imported the original settigs back so everything was restored).

Figure: I believe one of the folders shown in the image below has the key which needs to be changed in order to open excel macro files in separate windows.
[image]

Comment: The entry highlighted in your screenshot is for Excel 4 macro sheets, which were used to store the old style macros from before VBA was introduced.

Comment: I inserted the picture more for a general reference to all the excel options as well as to show the sub-menu which exists within these excel folders. I did not try to modify anything within Excel.Macrosheet. I tried to chang keys within Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12. Changing registry keys in the Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 directory did affect the behavior of the *.xlsm files when they were opened; just not in the way I had hoped.

Comment: Thanks for the response though

Answer (score 1):

You also need to delete the **command** REG_MULTI_SZ (the one with the seemingly gibberish-cryptographic value). Backup it in case it goes wrong!

Then, the XLSM files will open in a separate Excel program (notice the brief splash screen, which only appears when a new instance of Excel is created).

But be careful! In my tests, the order in which you open the file types make a big difference!

For example, if there is an Excel instance with a XLSM file open, and you open a XLSX file, it will try to reuse the existing Excel instance, because the registry associated to *Excel.Sheet.12* tells it to do it no matter the file type already open. Only XLSM files opened after an existing Excel instance is running will create its own instance of Excel.

I will search for a workaround, but I think this is enough for you to start the tests in your computer.